# Font Awesome desktop-useable font install

Tags: installation, font-awesome, truetype

I haven't been able to find a thread that solves my issue yet so opening this one up.  I'm trying to install the font but it is giving me an error on install.  We would like to use it in a desktop format initially so that document can be passed around internally and edited before putting on our site.  I have read it should be good 'our-of-the-box' to install with no issues, however, when trying to install the font this is the error message I get:

"Cannot install FontAwesome.otf
The file '\common.ecamericas...\FontAwesome.otf' does not appear to be a valid font"

This happens for the true type font file as well.  Any help would be appreciated so we could hash out which icons we would like to use without all getting in a single room together.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how to close this out but it appears it was an admin rights issue that wasn't letting it install fully/correctly.  I was able to get full rights and install it and it works perfect now.  Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it with admin or root account